# Difference between Inphase/Quadrature (I/Q) Mixer and I/Q Demodulator

Tags: rf, communication, mixer

I wanted to know the primary difference between an Inphase/Quadrature (I/Q) Demodulator and an I/Q Mixer.

**My requirements are as follows:**
My input signal is a 500 Mhz bandwidth signal centred around 4.25 Ghz. I need to obtain the I and Q components of the baseband signal with respect to the Local Oscillator( of 4.25 Ghz ).

Previously a Hittite chip [HMC620](http://www.hittite.com/products/view.html/view/HMC620I/Q Mixer) which has been described as a "mixer" in the datasheet. But I am unable to find an I/Q "mixer" from big companies like Texas Instruments or Analog Devices (the companies that are easily available). If my understanding is correct, an I/Q demodulator (TI and AD ics available) should also do the job I require.Is this correct?

**UPDATE 1 :**

The TI I/Q demodulator chip i am talking about is [TRF371135](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/trf371135) . while the Analog Devices one is [ADL5380](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADL5380.pdf). They do not exactly satisfy my 500Mhz bandwidth requirement, but they are the closest I could find on Digikey.

Are all I/Q demodulators I/Q mixers ? Or am I going fundamentally wrong somewhere ?

Thanks

Comment: Datasheets for the parts you're proposing to use would be helpful. TI and Analog aren't known for serving markets that use that high a frequency --- but I don't know their complete product lines...

Comment: I wonder where you can legal use 500 MHz of bandwidth :-)

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about this kind of RF myself, but I did find this information about what is an I/Q (de)modulator: http://www.minicircuits.com/app/MOD11-8.pdf

Comment: @Kellenjb : Yes it is, between 3.1 to 10.6 GHz as long as your signal in space satisfies power spectral density constraints ( -41.3 dBm/MHz) set by FCC. This is the basic idea behind [Ultra-Wideband Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-wideband).

Comment: Key point: "Q: Is there a difference between a modulator and demodulator at the same frequency?
A: Not much. Mini-Circuits' modulators and demodulators are tested for the specified function to confirm the specs. The higher the frequency, the greater the chance of a modulator not performing as well as a demodulator."

Comment: On the other hand, the datasheet for the TI demod part shows buffers on the I & Q outputs, so it probably cannot be used as a modulator -- meaning it does not function as a general-purpose mixer.

Comment: @ThePhoton : I didnt quite understand that statement Isn't there a fundamental difference between modulator and demodulator? Modulator : Inphase and Quadrature signals are your inputs while in a Demodulator you get the Inphase and Quadrature signals are outputs. Do they mean to say this can be interchangly used?

Comment: @gururaj, like I said this is not really my main area of expertise...I don't know how their mixer works, but note that Wikipedia's (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Diode_DBM.png) and another (http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/circuits/diode_double_balanced_mixer/diode_double_balanced_mixer.php) drawings of diode-based double-balanced mixers differ in which ports are labelled as inputs and which as outputs...Also, none of MCL's i/q mods or demods that I saw in a quick look supports your frequency band...so the technology they use may not be appropriate for you.

Comment: @gururaj I realize this is an old question, and you probably understand better now that a balanced mixer can be used to modulate and de-modulate. But it is unrealistic to expect the same part to work well for both as the signal levels are high and low respectively. Also it is unrealistic to expect a transformer to carry DC as well as more than 3 decades of frequency on input. Hence the modulation methods often exclude DC.. ALso conversion losses are high for demodulation and if error rate or BER is important, single stage conversion ( no IF  or heterodyne) has many tradeoffs.

Answer (score 5):

A mixer is just a circuit that multiplies two signals.

The purpose of a mixer is to shift a signal in the frequency domain.

Normally a mixer multiplies a signal carrying information (some range of frequencies, e.q. received signal or signal that is going to be tranmsitted) with a signal without information, consisting of exact one frequency (from the local oscillator).

An I/Q-Mixer consists of two ordinary mixers that each multiply the signal carring the information with the local oscillator signal, but one being 90° phase shifted.

A demodulator in general is a circuit that extracts the actual information of an RF signal.

There are many different demodulators (as there are many ways of modulation) and even for one particular modulation (e.g. FM, SSB) sometimes more than one type of demodulator is possible.

An I/Q demodulator is just some kind of demodulator using (among other subcircuits) an I/Q mixer as mentioned above.

Summary:
An I/Q mixer is a part of an I/Q demodulator.
An I/Q demodulator always contains an I/Q mixer, but I/Q mixers may also be used in circuits that are no demodulators (e.g. modulators).